# Does a frame buffer attached to a texture have to be bound to a texture unit?

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm trying to render to a frame buffer. I did this:

```
    renderer.gl_context.make_current();
    renderer.gl.GenFramebuffers(1, &mut fbo);
    renderer.gl.BindFramebuffer(gl::FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    renderer.gl.GenTextures(1, &mut tex);
    renderer.gl.BindTexture(gl::TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    renderer.gl.TexImage2D(
        gl::TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        gl::RGB as i32,
        width as i32,
        height as i32,
        0,
        gl::RGB,
        gl::UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        std::ptr::null() as *const libc::c_void,
    );
    renderer.gl.TexParameteri(
        gl::TEXTURE_2D,
        gl::TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
        gl::LINEAR.try_into().unwrap(),
    );
    renderer.gl.TexParameteri(
        gl::TEXTURE_2D,
        gl::TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
        gl::LINEAR.try_into().unwrap(),
    );
    renderer.gl.FramebufferTexture2D(
        gl::FRAMEBUFFER,
        gl::COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        gl::TEXTURE_2D,
        tex,
        0,
    );
```

but the drawing code makes use of other textures as well, and they are bound to `GL_TEXTURE0` to `GL_TEXTURE_2`. I'm always calling `renderer.gl.BindFramebuffer(gl::FRAMEBUFFER, fbo)` before drawing, but the drawing calls use `GL_TEXTURE0` to `GL_TEXTURE_2`, so where is the `tex` texture bound? Should I bind it to a texture unit before drawing? Should this texture unit be different from `GL_TEXTURE0` to `GL_TEXTURE_2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to bind the framebuffer texture to a texture unit while render to the FBO. The texture is associate with the framebuffer object, and when you bind the FBO before rendering, everything will be setup correctly.

In your code, you only need the binding for `TexParameteri` and `TexImage2D`, but even `FramebufferTexture2D` does not need the texture to be bound.

As a rule of thumb: If a method takes the handle to an object, then it doesn't need the object to be bound.

Comment: so after I create and bound the frame buffer to a texture, I can just bind only the frame buffer before each draw call? It doesn't matter if I use 10 textures and texture units after the frame buffer is bound? Asking because currently I see nothing rendered, I tried all possible combinations

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Texture units have nothing to do with render targets. But since you are rendering to an FBO, why are you expecting to see anything? How are you transfering the framebuffer content to the backbuffer? If you render a full-screen quad with the FBO texture on it, then you need to bind the FBO texture for a texture unit for that pass.

Comment: flutter copies the image from the `tex` and renders to the screen. Therefore if I render, with an FBO, to `tex`, it should appear there. However something is wrong